# How to see logging output in embedded python interpreter?

Tags: python, logging, interpreter

I'm using embedded python interpreter in my iOS app. I'm able to see `print` output in Xcode console, but i'm unable to see any `logging.info()` or `logging.debug()` output. How can i enable it?

My test python code:

```
import logging
import sys

# try to add logging output to stdout
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()

log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

# for calling from outside
def main__(args):
    print("main__()") # can see output
    print type(args)
    print len(args)
    for eachArg in args:
#        print('#: %s' % eachArg) # can see output
        logging.info(eachArg) # can NOT see output
```

Output is:

```
main__()
<type 'list'>
281
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the stuff is in debug level.
This code works for me:

```
import logging
import sys

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stream.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(stream)

# for calling from outside
def main__(args):
    print("main__()") # can see output
    print type(args)
    print len(args)
    for eachArg in args:
        logging.info(eachArg)
```

output:

```
>>> main__('test')
main__()
<type 'str'>
4
t
e
s
t
>>>
```

Comment: you're absolutely right! i expected `logging.INFO` to be default logging level and that was wrong. Use `log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`. BTW i found setting log level for handler not required